# how to parallelize vacuuming delta tables in AWS?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, delta

I am trying to optimize my vacuum/optimize jobs on databricks. I was reading this [blog post](https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/delta/vacuum-best-practices-on-delta-lake) for vacuuming delta tables and as far as I understand, running vacuum on AWS is a single threaded process. Are there ways to parallelize the vacuum process across multiple cores? Or does it only occur on a single thread/core at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Set "`spark.databricks.delta.vacuum.parallelDelete.enabled`" to "`true`" and I think it will do what you're asking for.

Couple of useful links:

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table

https://github.com/delta-io/delta/pull/522